# TypeError: Object(..) is not a function at InAppPurchase2.get

Tags: ionic, ionic3, pago-in-app

Amigos una consulta, alguien ha realizado "in-app purchase" con el plugin "j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase"? Lo que sucede es que lo integré a mi proyecto pero no pude realizar ninguna compra y al hacer un console.log del objeto "store" de la clase "InAppPurchase2" (la cuál estoy importando), me salen varios errores como si no se hubiera instalado bien el plugin, pero lo he reinstalado varias veces y he probado con varias versiones de platform android y sigue sin funcionar..

Los comandos que uso para instalarlo son estos:

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-purchase [--variable BILLING_KEY=""]

luego:

npm install @ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2

[image: Error del objeto store]

Por favor si alguien sabe se lo agradecería un montón!!

Comment: que tal Halen, bienvenido... nos muestras los comandos y nos muestras la consola, pero no vemos tu código mas allá que dices que los has importado... muchísimos de los problemas planteados en SO son por errores de código... Seria bueno que para poder ayudarte mejor nos muestres un poco del código correspondiente a lo que pides para partir de ahí... Mientras tanto seria bueno que te des una vuelta por [ask] para mas información...

Comment: Hola Victor, gracias por responder.. al final pude solucionar mi problema instalando el in-app-purchase con otro comando:

npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2@4

Lo dejo aquí por si alguien más se ve en el mismo error. Gracias por tu interés en ayudarme, tomaré en cuenta tus comentarios para mi próxima pregunta